# apache_beam: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: DATE, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam-io

I did some python coding with BQ SQL using apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools.

What I am confused about is the SQL is working perfectly when I run in BQ, but it hits an error when I implement it to Python with the above apache_beam library. I also tried many workarounds to cast the variable into the date but was far from successful.

The snapshot of the SQL that working in BQ is:

```
/*===============================
 DECLARE REPORTING DATE VARIABLE
================================*/
DECLARE varReportingDT date;
SET     varReportingDT = "2021-11-14";

Select some fields
from some table
Where
some conditions...

(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", (s.sys_update_date)) > '2021-09-02'
and (FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", (s.sys_update_date)) > '2021-09-02' 
      and DATE_ADD(DATE(s.sys_update_date), INTERVAL 74 DAY) = CAST(varReportingDT as DATE))
    )
)
```

and below is the snapshot when I implement it to the Python

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import DebugOptions

.... some scripts ....

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    """Main entry point; defines and runs the wordcount pipeline."""
    # noinspection DuplicatedCode
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--reporting_date',
        dest='reporting_date',
        default=yesterday_local().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
        help='reporting date for execution')

.... some scripts ....
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_args.extend([
        # '--runner=DataflowRunner',
        '--project=' + known_args.project

.... some scripts .....

(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", (s.sys_update_date)) > '2021-09-02'
and (FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", (s.sys_update_date)) > '2021-09-02'
      and DATE_ADD(DATE(s.sys_update_date), INTERVAL 74 DAY) = CAST({ known_args.reporting_date } as DATE))
    )
)
```

Below is the line 52 on the code:

[image: line 52]

And below is the select statement that feed the data insert:

[image: select statement]

And this is the corresponding error to that Python:

```
INFO:apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools:Failed to insert job <JobReference
 jobId: \'beam_bq_job_QUERY_masked-by-me\'
 projectId: \'test'>: HttpError accessing <https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/masked-by-me/jobs?alt=json>: response: <{\'vary\': \'Origin, X-Origin, Referer\', \'content-type\': \'application/json; charset=UTF-8\', \'date\': \'Mon, 15 Nov 2021 12:46:57 GMT\', \'server\': \'ESF\', \'cache-control\': \'private\', \'x-xss-protection\': \'0\', \'x-frame-options\': \'SAMEORIGIN\', \'x-content-type-options\': \'nosniff\', \'transfer-encoding\': \'chunked\', \'status\': \'400\', \'content-length\': \'359\', \'-content-encoding\': \'gzip\'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid cast from INT64 to DATE at [52:91]",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid cast from INT64 to DATE at [52:91]",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidQuery",
        "location": "q",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Comment: "Invalid cast from INT64 to DATE at [52:91]" sounds fairly specific. Check line 52 of the SQL in your script. I'm guessing there's a variable-substitution in there that doesn't work the way you expect in the Python, so that the SQL passed doesn't exactly match what you've tested in BigQuery. If that doesn't work, construct a minimal example: Copy your Python to a new file and hard-code all variables.  Then iteratively strip out portions of the Python and SQL until you isolate a small change which lets you turn the error on / off.  SO can't diagnose the problem with so much of your script MIA.

Comment: Based on the error code that you are receiving, it looks like in line 52 of your Python code something is missing. What you pass into your code might be changed or a variable is missing for the ones you are directing from BQ.

Comment: Hi @SarahMesser, thank you for your suggestions. Yes, I have slowly check the with the simplest SQL part-by-part, the original SQL was hardcoded the date criteria below with some date, but once I put in the python variable { known_args.reporting_date } then the issue start appearing.



SQL line that worked previously: and FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", (s.sys_update_date)) <= FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", '2021-10-31')

Answer (score 1):

I manage to find the cause, it was because I missed the apostrophe symbol before and after the curly bracket.

```
--problem
and DATE_ADD(DATE(s.sys_update_date), INTERVAL 74 DAY) = CAST({ known_args.reporting_date } as DATE)

--solved
and DATE_ADD(DATE(s.sys_update_date), INTERVAL 74 DAY) = CAST('{ known_args.reporting_date }' as DATE)
```

well... the lesson learnt from this is sometimes I just need to relax a little bit, drink coffee/tea, release the muscle tense then revisit back the codes.

Anw... thanks for Sarah and Eduardo paying some visits and dropping your comments.

Cheers,

*just a developer with a tight timeline*